# find the eigenvalues of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are the eigenvalues of the following $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix:
$$
M=A-A^T,
$$
where $n>2$ can be odd or even, and
$A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ has $a_{1,n}=-1$ and $a_{ij}=1$ for $j=i+1, i=1,\dots, 
n-1$.

Comment: What makes you expect a closed form exists?

Comment: For $n=5$, the characteristic polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ as $x \cdot (x^{4} + 5 x^{2} + 5)$. I don't think you should expect anything nice.

Comment: @darijgrinberg That particular example is not particularly bad (the roots of $x^4+5x^2+5$ are just the two square roots of the two roots of $x^2+5x+5$). But I suspect it will eventually get very bad.

Answer (score 2):

$$\{\zeta^{r}-\zeta^{-r}|r=0,\dots,n-1\}$$
where $\zeta$ is some primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Edited to provide more information.

To see this note that we are looking at the matrix $\Omega-\Omega^{-1}$, where $\Omega$ is the simple circulant that permutes the basis vectors in an $n$-cycle. The eigenvalues of $\Omega$ are well-known, being the powers of $\zeta$; the matrix formed by the putting the eigenvectors as columns is $\left(\zeta^{(i-1)(j-1)}\right)$.

Comment: @John Your $M$ is an instance of [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), which have a general eigenvalue formula.

Comment: @user1551 4 A difference of a circulant and its inverse surely?

Comment: Yes, but $M$ itself is also circulant: it has two circulant diagonals, one extending from the $(1,2)$-th entry (with coefficient $1$) and the other from the $(1,n)$-th entry (with coefficient $-1$). The set of all circulant matrices actually form an algebra.

Comment: @user1551. Sorry, I see "circulant" is wider in meaning than I had supposed. It doesn't affect the maths, though.  It would be good to know where this problem arises: or is it just an exercise?

Comment: I guess it isn't, but only @John knows.

Comment: Oh, so it is indeed circulant, that's a bit counterintuitive to me. Is $A+A^T$ circulant? It looks like it isn't...

Comment: @Ian $A+A^T$ is not circulant, but the entries of its eigenvectors still satisfy a 2nd order recurrence equation, so there should be a closed-form formula for the eigenvalues.

Comment: @ancientmathematician , could you please show how you get the eigenvalues?

Comment: @John: edited as requested. Can you explain where this problem comes from? I once handled a similar thing in Physics ..

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I am doing a finite-difference method for a partial differential equation (PDE).